# Will I lose the data from my disk if I switch from SSD to HDD in a azure VM?

Tags: azure, scaling, azure-vm

I have $500 to spend in Azure credits. I noticed that the SSD costs to much, So I want to switch from an SSD disk to an HDD disk. I was wondering if I switch will my data be lost? I apologize for the poor grammar in this question. Please comment if you need me to make my question more clear.

Comment: I do feel you cant change the disk type. you will have to create a new one, copy to it then you can delete the old or something like that.

Comment: Oh, i saw this article though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-disk-storage @Thomas

Comment: Then, i'm wrong ^^ sorry for my previous comment

Comment: Its fine ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵  ឵឵

Comment: If your wondering how to change it, go to Size + Performance in the disk account and you can change it. I'm just worried it will reinstall the os, or erase my data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert VM OS disk from Premium SSD disk to Standard HDD disk.

Your data won't be lost.

Configuration example from Azure Portal:

1. Select the VM from the list of Virtual machines.
2. If the VM isn't stopped, select Stop at the top of the VM Overview pane, and wait for the VM to stop.
3. In the pane for the VM, select Disks from the menu.
4. Select the disk that you want to convert.
5. Select Configuration from the menu.
6. Change the Account type from the original disk type to the desired disk type.

[image]

https://www.unixarena.com/2019/12/azure-how-to-convert-disk-from-premium-to-standard-ssd-vice-versa.html/

Configuration example using CLI:

```
#resource group that contains the managed disk
rgName='yourResourceGroup'

#Name of your managed disk
diskName='yourManagedDiskName'

#Premium capable size 
#Required only if converting from Standard to Premium
size='Standard_DS2_v2'

#Choose between Standard_LRS, StandardSSD_LRS and Premium_LRS based on your scenario
sku='Premium_LRS'

#Get the parent VM Id 
vmId=$(az disk show --name $diskName --resource-group $rgName --query managedBy --output tsv)

#Deallocate the VM before changing the size of the VM
az vm deallocate --ids $vmId 

#Change the VM size to a size that supports Premium storage 
#Skip this step if converting storage from Premium to Standard
az vm resize --ids $vmId --size $size

# Update the SKU
az disk update --sku $sku --name $diskName --resource-group $rgName 

az vm start --ids $vmId
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-disk-storage